# Spring boot get size of aws s3 bucket

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am working on web application using aws s3 where i upload and download file from s3 bucket.

```
@Bean
    public BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials() {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    }

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3Client() {
        AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAWSCredentials()))
                .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1)
                .build();
        return s3client;
    }
```

this is my beans

and i want to get size of bucket where i pass bucketName and function will return size of that bucket.

Please let me know how i can get size of bucket?

Answer (score 0):

> Please let me know how i can get size of bucket?

Probably the easiest way would be to query latest [BucketSizeBytes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html#s3-cloudwatch-dimensions) metric from CloudWatch from your bucket. The metric:

> The **amount of data in bytes stored in a bucket** in the STANDARD storage class, INTELLIGENT_TIERING storage class, Standard - Infrequent Access (STANDARD_IA) storage class, OneZone - Infrequent Access (ONEZONE_IA), Reduced Redundancy Storage (RRS) class, Deep Archive Storage (S3 Glacier Deep Archive) class or, Glacier (GLACIER) storage class. This value is calculated by summing the size of all objects in the bucket (both current and noncurrent objects), including the size of all parts for all incomplete multipart uploads to the bucket.

The metric is reported **once-per-day**, thus if you require real-time size, you have to create a custom solution for that. This would involve keeping metadata of your object, such as size, in, for example, DynamoDb, and pulling current size from there.

Comment: is there any java code exists for get size of database?